# Is BlobContainerClient in azure c++ sdk thread safe?

Tags: c++, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

In the following code

```
#include "azure/storage/blobs/blob_container_client.hpp"
#include "azure/storage/blobs/block_blob_client.hpp"
#include "azure/core.hpp"
#include "azure/identity/client_secret_credential.hpp"

auto clientCertificateCredential
  = std::make_shared<Azure::Identity::ClientSecretCredential>(tenantId, applicationId, applicationSecret);
client = std::make_shared<Azure::Storage::Blobs::BlobContainerClient>(url, clientCertificateCredential);
```

Can I have n threads using client to perform download/upload and listing operation? Is it thread safe (and how many thread can we spawn), or each thread should have its own BlobContainerClient?

Comment: I think this MS issue is relevant [Thread safety and suggested lifetime patterns of storage classes not documented](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/732#issuecomment-559277954)

Comment: Very few things are thread-safe unless they state that they are thread-safe.  And even then, the thread-safety is typically not transitive.  (And the situations when it is transitive will probably be a problem.)